# Создание массивов из текста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, lua, match

У меня например есть строка

```
s = "Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?"
```

Мне нужно разделить с помощью выражений, а именно функцией string.gmatch, на массив который будет вмещать в себе масивы с цвета R, G, B и самой строки. То есть чтобы в результате я получил массив:

```
arr[1] = {0, 0, 0, "Hello, world! "}
// Из-за того что в начале строки нет кода цвета, то по умолчанию ставить цвет по нулям

arr[2] = {255, 0, 0, "Привет, мир! "}

arr[3] = {155, 55, 0, "How are {100,3,5you?"}
// "How are {100,3,5you?" - именно так, по скольку неправильно сформирован код цвета, также если будет например буква внутри {100,3Я,5}, то это также все пойдет в строку
```

Вот что у меня получилось написать на LUA:

```
arr = {}
s = "Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?"
for k, v in string.gmatch(s, "{(%d+,%d+,%d+)}([^{]*)") do
    local r, g, b = string.match(k, "(%d+),(%d+),(%d+)")
    table.insert(arr, {r, g, b, v})
end
```

В результате получаю массив:

```
arr[1] = {255, 0, 0, "Привет, мир! "}
arr[2] = {155, 55, 0, "How are "}
```

Но меня это не устраивает:

1) нет части строки, в которой не указан цвет, то есть нет массива 
`arr[1] = {0, 0, 0, "Hello, world! "}`

2) Обрезает до следующего символа `{`, а нужно чтобы обрезало до комбинации цвета

Как по-другому это реализовать (но в простом варианте, то есть так, чтобы не было большой нагрузки), или хотя бы как например такое реализовать в *PHP*, а я бы попытался уже как-то перевести на *LUA*

Answer (score 2):

> Может кто-то знает как по другому это реализовать (но в простом варианте, тоесть так чтобы не было большой нагрузки), или хотя бы как например такое реализовать в PHP

Вот такая реализация:

```
$s = "Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?";
$res = [];
// Делим предложение 
$words = explode(" {", $s);
foreach($words as $k => $w){
    // цвета R, G, B
    preg_match('/(\d+,\d+,\d+)\}?/', $w, $match);
    if(!empty($match)){
        // Только текст без цветов R, G, B
        preg_match('/[^(\d+,\d+,\d+)\}?].+/', $w, $not_m);
        $res[] = [$match[1], $not_m[0]];
    }else{
        $res[] = ['0,0,0', $w];
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Получаем результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0,0,0
            [1] => Hello, world!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 255,0,0
            [1] => Привет, мир!
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 155,55,0
            [1] => How are
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100,3,5
            [1] => you?
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам вариант без циклов:

```
$text = '{100,0,0}Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?';
$str = array_filter(preg_split('~{(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)}~', $text));

preg_match_all('~(.+?){~', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$result = array_map(function ($x, $y) {
    return (!preg_match_all('/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/', $x[0], $match))
    ? [0, 0, 0, $y]
    : [$match[1][0], $match[2][0], $match[3][0], $y];
}, $matches, $str);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Но результат нужен такой: `arr[3] = {155, 55, 0, "How are {100,3,5you?"}` :>

Comment: @Manitikyl, черт, вы правы, исправил)

Comment: Теперь у этой фразы, цвет '0,0,0' а должен быть другой. P.S. Щас мы с вами доведем до ума :D

Comment: @Manitikyl, ой, гребанные проблемы)))), ща попробую исправить)

Comment: Вы уже чувствуете что попахивает дикими костылями? :D

Comment: @Manitikyl, исправил, но выглядит прикольно все равно :D

Comment: Не спешите праздновать победу сударь, а вот с такой строкой косячит: `$text = '{100,0,0}Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?';`

Comment: @Manitikyl, вынужден уйти в депрессию :(, пересмотрю попозже(

Comment: Пора открывать коробочку с костылями ;)

Comment: @Manitikyl, исправил :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//  TEXT
$text = "Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?";

//  PARSE
preg_match_all("#{(\d+,\d+,\d+)}#Uu", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_SET_ORDER); 

//  VAR
$result = [];
$color = '0,0,0';
$offset = 0;
//  EACH
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    $text_sub = substr($text, $offset, ($value[0][1] - $offset));
    if (mb_strlen($text_sub) > 0) {
        $result[] = array_merge(explode(',', $color), [$text_sub]);
    }
    $offset = $value[0][1] + mb_strlen($value[0][0]);
    $color = $value[1][0];
}
//  LAST
$text_sub = substr($text, $offset);
if (mb_strlen($text_sub) > 0) {
    $result[] = array_merge(explode(',', $color), [$text_sub]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Может и костыльно, но то что вам нужно, делает.

Comment: Голос за костыли, ведь люди со сломанными ногами не могут без них прожить, хд :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно так получилось:

```
s = "Hello, world! {255,0,0}Привет, мир! {155,55,0}How are {100,3,5you?"
s =   s  .. "\n" -- вынужденная мера, обозначим конец строки
arr = {}
local arr = {{0,0,0,""}}
local i=1
for  case in s:gmatch ("(.-[%c}])") do
        -- print ( case )
        local text = case:match("(.+){")
        local r, g, b = case:match( "{(%d+),(%d+),(%d+)}")
        if r and g and b then 
            arr[i+1] = {r,g,b,""}
        else 
            text = case 
        end
        arr[i][4] = text
        i=i+1
end

-- test
 for k,v in pairs(arr) do
    print(k, v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4])
 end
```

результат:

```
1   0   0   0   Hello, world! 
2   255 0   0   Привет, мир! 
3   155 55  0   How are {100,3,5you?
```